# Link github to git doesn't require password

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and Github.
  I've inited a local Git repo "dummy" repo and a remote Github repo "dummy". Now I want to link them together in the Git command line as follows:

```
git remote add origin http:s//github.com/myusername/dummy.git
```

The above works fine.
  My question is: why doesn't the command line require me entering the password on the Github account? It seems insecure in that anyone claiming to be myself by entering "myusername" can link to my Github account.
  Thanks!

Cheers,
M.

Comment: Did you notice the `https://` is messed up? Fixing that might save you some pain later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to enter credentials when you're pushing your local repository to your Github repository.

You only added a remote to your local repository right now. To actually push your files to your Github repository you have to execute `git push` which will then ask for your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the new remote simply adds it to a configuration file. Git won't need the password until it actually interacts with the repo (by fetching, pulling, pushing, etc).

```
$ git fetch origin
```

will require a password *if* the repository is private.

```
$ git push origin
```

will require a password no matter what.